# Database engine that supports multiple primary keys?

Tags: database, relational-database, primary-key

Is there any database engine out there that supports multiple primary keys?

And no, I am not asking about multiple fields in a single primary key.

I understand that the engine will have to duplicate the data for each of additional primary keys. That is  fine with me.

Has anyone out there implemented that feature?

Comment: I have no idea what "duplicated the data" means. But, yes if you have multiple unique indexes on a table, there will be additional disk storage consumed to support those indexes.

Comment: Read a definition of "PK". There can only be one. So it does not make sense to talk about multiple ones. Explain what property a set of columns has for *you* to (erroneously) call it a PK in this question. (Maybe you mean CK.) Also "duplicate the data for each of additional primary keys" is not clear. Please edit your question to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

A set of columns that is unique is a superkey. A superkey that contains no smaller/proper superkey is a CK (candidate key). One CK can be called "the" PK (primary key).

It does not make sense to talk about multiple PKs. Maybe when you say PK you mean CK or superkey (or maybe even some kind of SQL index) but you don't clarify what you mean.

SQL only allows one `primary key` declaration per table. But it means `unique not null`. So in relational terms `primary key` declares a superkey, but not necessarily a CK or PK. (Although a DBMS might treat PKs differently in some other way.) An SQL `foreign key` must reference columns that are `unique not null` (maybe via  `primary key`) but in relaational terms that makes it a foreign superkey, not a FK (foreign key).

(When NULLs are involved in SQL other relational terms also don't apply because there is no NULL in relational theory.)